# Where clause for list of roles asp.net mvc identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have the following variable which selects all the roles the current signed in user is in:

```
var roles = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims
    .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
    .Select(c => c.Value);
```

I want to be able to filter this list for just the roles that have Club at the beginning and Admin at the end.

The roles are made up of the word Club, the clubs Id and Admin.

Ive tried to add contains clauses to it with no luck as yet.

Comment: `StartsWith and EndsWith`

Comment: Thanks, I'm still learning, how to I implement those? @MethodMan

Comment: var roles = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims
    .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role && c.Value.StartsWith("Club") && c.Value.EndsWith("Admin"))
    .Select(c => c.Value);

Comment: thanks @lyz just the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @lyz for the answer:

```
            var roles = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims
            .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role && c.Value.StartsWith("Club") && c.Value.EndsWith("Admin"))
            .Select(c => c.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var roleFilter = string.Format("Club{0}Admin", clubId);    
var roles = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims
                .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role && roleFilter.Equals(c.Value)
                .Select(c => c.Value);
```

optionally, you could use StringComparison IgnoreCase options in the equality check if you want.

Comment: Thanks @Scottley but that will only return ones with the same clubId I need all club Id's

Comment: then just modify the roleFilter.Equals check to be whatever other boolean operation you need.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use `Claims`, of course, but there are some other things (and simplier) to get current user roles.

The first one is to use `UserManager<TUser>` class which is an instance `IUserManager<TUser>` interface. When you create default project it stored as a property in your controllers. This class a lot of useful methods to work with user accounts itself (creating, editing, deleting) and with user roles also (assign, unassign and retrieve them). Moreover, using this manager you could be 1000% sure that if someone changed user roles 1 second ago you'll get appropriate user roles **always**

The second one is to use built in `IsInRole(string role)` method of `User` controllers' property. It returns true if currently logged in user has specified role or false if not. This approach are little bit "unstable" because it relies on `User` data which is an instance of `IPrincipal` and is assigned when your user is logging in. Changing current user roles if he is currently logged in can takes place **only after you'll give this user with log out and then log him in again**. This is because you need to reassign instance of `IdentityUser` instance to current `IPrincipal`. Moreover, this is also true for `Claims` array of `ClaimsIdentity`. But if you sure that this is not possible in your system - you can forget about it.

Also if you have your roles defined in roles enumeration its better to create your own extension method for `User` that will take your roles enumeration value instead of calling `ToString()` at each call to built in `IsInRole()`:

```
public static bool IsInRole(this IPrincipal principal, RolesEnum value)
{
    return principal.IsInRole(value.ToString());
}
```

Also you can create your own helper methods in the same way to check your roles if you want to.

If you prefer to use `LINQ` query just replace your `Where` expression with this:

```
.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role && c.Value.StartsWith(startValeu) && c.Value.EndsWith(endValue))
```